# Want to run a simple C program on startup of pi

Tags: boot, led, c

Im new to linux and the pi . Im stuck with this situation where
Iv been trying to run a simple LED blinking  C code as a test , so that it will be executed during startup

Code works fine when its executed from its folder indicating its a working code
What I have done so far is

**1.** I put direction to the folder and command to run code in `/etc/rc.local`  ie

```
cd home/pi/C_Codes
```

and then run
    sudo ./blink.c

It work on 1st boot, but 2nd boot onwards it crashes and fails, but the pi does boot up, without any output(blinking of LED)

**2.** After creating new script(copy paste) as

```
/etc/init.d/blink_startup.c
```

I would run 
    update-rc.d blink_startup.c enable

it gives error saying

```
blink_startup.c Default - Start contains no run levels
```

**3.** After running in root terminal, i gave `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/blink_startup.c`
to check program and then gave update to make it work on booting - `update-rc.d blink_startup.c defaults` it gives the error - `insserv: warning:script 'K01blink_startup.c' missing LSB tags and overrides`

If someone could assist me and guide me through the situation to tackle this, would really appreciate it

Good Day

Comment: C is a compiled language.  I.e. the source code is compiled into an executable and the executable is run.  A file with name blink.c suggests a C source file, not an executable file.  What does blink.c contain?

Comment: @joan already mentioned the fact that the c-file (that is source code not an executable script) needs compiling first. On the other hand the scripts in the `init.d`-framework are something completely separate.

Comment: Couldnt you just have cron run your script on @reboot

Answer (score 5):

1. > command to run code in /etc/rc.local

   Three things to remember when putting commands in `rc.local`:

   - Don't use `sudo`, because the script is run as root anyway.
   - Unless the command exits quickly, it must fork to the background.  This is accomplished by adding `&` to the end:

     ```
     mycommand &
     ```
   - `$PATH` *may* not be set. This is a list of directories where the shell searches for commands.  To be sure, you need to either do something like this at the beginning of the script:

     ```
      export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
     ```

   Or use absolute paths with all commands.  You can find these normally with `which`.
2. > I would run update-rc.d blink_startup.c enable

   As a few people have pointed out, conventionally a `.c` file is source code.  If this is a shell script in `/etc/init.d`, it should be suffixed with `.sh`.  **It also must conform to the rules described in `/etc/init.d/README`,** which is why you are getting an error.
3. See #2, re: the rules this must conform to.

Comment: is there a way to test changes to rc.local so you can see if you have set up your commands correctly? Can you run rc.local to see if there are errors from a ssh command line?

Comment: @Roger Presuming your commands have some kind of output, you can do something like `myapp &> /tmp/myapp.log &`.  The `&>` redirects standard output and standard error; the final `&` ensures it forks to background (which it needs to unless it is going to exit quickly -- I've updated this answer re that).  If your commands won't produce any output, but exit quickly, *don't* fork (no final `&`), and you can check the exit status with the shell's `$?` variable.  If your commands don't produce any output but are persist or don't vary their exit status, find whoever wrote them and tell them off ;)

Comment: Sorry, not sure I quite understand you (brand new to Pi and to linux). The app I am attempting to run takes command line arguments. Won't it just try to consume what you suggested? Should start my own question instead of trying to add on here?

Comment: The arguments should go *before* the output redirection (`&> log`), and the fork (`&`) should be at the very end.  WRT general linux questions, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate place to ask about things like this.  This question was really off-topic in the first place, since it does not involve the pi in a relevant way (the particular hardware doesn't matter).  Unless you see a definite connection to the hardware, assume you have a general linux question.

Comment: Tried what you suggested, and did not get anything. Agree I am off topic, moving here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189411/understanding-rc-local-and-troubleshooting

Comment: That's a good answer, actually.

Answer (score 1):

On recent versions of Raspbian, you can use a cron job for this.

Run `crontab -e` and select your favorite editor when prompted, then add the following to the bottom of the file:

```
@reboot /path/to/executable
```